# Heroku process.env.PORT variable gets set to an outofrange value

Tags: javascript, heroku, node.js

I'm trying to build a webproject that works fine on localhost locally, but doesn't work when I upload it to heroku. I've added a Procfile with the text: `web: npm start` which correctly runs `node index.js` as it's supposed to. However, when it gets to listening to a port, it recieves way to high numbers as the port number (in the range of 300.000 and up). Here's an example from last run: `RangeError [ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT]: options.port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received 350251.`.

Here is my code for listening:

```
httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app)
httpServer = http.createServer(app)


const httpPort = process.env.PORT || 80;
const httpsPort = process.env.PORT + 1 || 443;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/.webpages/' + webpage + '/public'))
httpsServer.listen(httpsPort, () => console.log('HTTPS server listening on port ' + httpsPort))
httpServer.listen(httpPort, () => console.log('HTTP server listening on port ' + httpPort))
```

Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what it looks like, process.env.PORT is interpreted as a string then adding +1 concatenates the value, and then gets translated to an integer, this might be causing the issue.

Ex:

'35025' + 1 = '350251' which coincides with the out of range port number.

you should not be adding +1 to the port number variable

Comment: Thank you a lot. Nice catch! I would probably have been going at it for at least another few hours!